# Why are my SMS messages not displaying correctly in my list?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, sms, contacts

I'm creating a custom SMS app like Handcent, Chomp, textPlus, and Pansi SMS. What I'm current trying to emulate is the inbox like this, but with just the **contact name** and **latest message** received in **textviews:** http://venturebeat.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/pinger_sms_free_inbox_android.png

In my SMSList class (extends Activity), this method is passed into my CustomAdapter constructor:
http://pastebin.com/TgsshJbc

In my CustomAdapter class, an arraylist called elements holds the data from from the above method. So when do this:

```
textview1.setText(elements.get(position);
```

this will return all text messages with all the correct corresponding phone numbers.

***Here is the problem:***

I need to separate the phone number and pass it into the **textview1** and pass the message into **textview2.** I've tried creating:

```
List<String> contactNo = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> message = new ArrayList<String>();
ListIterator<String> it;
contactNo = elements;
message = elements;

it = contactNo.listIterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    it.set(it.next().split(" ")[0]); // Keep the number, discard the message
}

it = messages.listIterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    it.set(it.next().split(" ")[1]); // Keep the message, discard the number
}
```

When I try contactNo in textview1, works fine. But messages in textview2 causes list errors and displays nothing.

***Problem Two:***
When applying the code this way (without using elements other than to get the size), The phone numbers display correctly, but the messages repeat itself after the 7th message. **Please note that I have 129 text messages in total, so throughout my list of 129 items, I get the first 7 messages displayed 18 times:**

http://pastebin.com/dJy2ie9g

**GOAL:**

My goal is to read each both phone number and their message within two seperate textviews per list item correctly just like reading both into one textview. The reason for the separation is for styling purposes. Does anyone have any ideas as to why I'm having bugs with the first and second problem?

Answer (score 0):

wrt to the second problem: the call to
        `holder.latestSMS.setText(messages.get(position); // Display text message segment`
should be outside the '`if`' statement (ie it should also be called when `convertView!=null`)

You can not assume that the `convertView` passed to `getView` matches the `position` parameter